# Changing `filetype` based on the current `filetype`

Tags: vim

How do I get the current `filetype` of a file into a variable?

I'm basically trying to set a key to switch between `html` and `php` filetypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&filetype`, like in this simplistic function.

```
function ToggleFT()
  if &filetype == 'html'
    set filetype=php
  elseif &filetype == 'php'
    set ft=html
  endif
endfunction
```